# remote: Internal Server ErrorEverything up-to-date when cloning repo to github

Tags: git, github, github-enterprise

Im trying to clone repo from GitBlit to Github enterprise .

I use the following command :

> git clone  --mirror https://old_repo.git
>
> git remote add new-origin https://new_repo.git
>
> git push  new-origin --mirror

The thing is after the push i get :

```
remote: Internal Server ErrorEverything up-to-date
```

and the New_repo is empty 
what am i missing ? 
i need to add this method worked on smaller repos but not the mail one , about 1G  . 
We have 15k tags and 2500 branches .

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem happened because of github enterprise limitation of numbers of tags 
you can push up to 1k tag simultaneously.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to perform this successfully using the following set of commands:

```
$ git clone --mirror https://old_repo.git
$ cd old_repo.git
$ git push --mirror https://new.git
```

> This will get all the branches and tags that are available in the upstream repository and will replicate those into the new location.

Comment: yes it worked with other repos , but not on the main one , i guess coz its bigger